# why the pygments highlight has a background color?

Tags: highlight, jekyll, pygments

I am trying to build a blog using jekyll,and I want to highlight my code,after some search on the internt,I realize that I can use pygments.I install python-2.7.5,and install pygments.

I install pygments with gem,the version pygments is 0.5.0.

now the problem is no mater what theme I use,there always is a background color with the code,like this:http://happyroc.github.io/2013/11/07/hello/
the code `int a = 1;`has a background color #fee9cc

```
# This is the default format. 
# For more see: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title 

exclude: [".rvmrc", ".rbenv-version", "README.md", "Rakefile", "changelog.md"]
markdown: redcarpet
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables",       "with_toc_data"]
pygments: true
```

how this happen?

Comment: I am sorry that I accidentally deleted the page,now I hava add the page,the new url is :http://happyroc.github.io/2013/11/07/hello/ @user1177636

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bootstrap is responsible. Check you bootstrap.css file